# Get Android OS version from user-agent

Tags: android, version, user-agent

I've been trying to find a parser or regex that will give me the Android OS version from a user agent string.

E.g.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; fr-fr; Desire HD Build/FRG83D) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

Will return:

```
2.2.1
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Related android blog's post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-browser-user-agent-issues.html

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/25303065?noredirect=1

Answer (score 24):

This regular expression is a bit more "future proof" than [mathepic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293394/get-android-os-version-from-user-agent/5293488#5293488):

```
Android (\d+(?:\.\d+)*);
```

It allows for multiple digits in each place as well as additional periods in the version number. Android's been out 3 years and we're on 3.0. Eventually we'll get to 10.0.0.

This will catch all of the following:

- 1.6 (real)
- 2.3.4 (real)
- 9
- 12.34.56 (fake. but one day...)
- 3.4.5.6 and 4.5.6.7.8.9 (fake... but just in case)

This could be written a little more strictly as:

```
Android (\d+(?:\.\d+){0,2});
```

This sticks more closely to the schema we've already seen used, but could potentially miss some versions of they decide to add an additional `.1` at the end of a version. It also matches for the future `10.0.0` version.

Comment: Careful: this will also match "DefinitelyNotAndroid 0.0" ;-) You might want to append a `\b` to the front.

Comment: And since we're talking about future-proofing: I'd avoid hard-coding `;` and replace it with `[;)]` or `\b`. A theoretical paranoid version  *might* use `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1)`.

Comment: Fair enough, +1 I suppose. It looks a little nicer but I also think its somewhat more difficult to understand. In any case I probably should have used +'s on my digits.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: If anything, I'd solve it going the other direction. `; Android (\d+(?:\.\d+)+)` which might not be a bad call. I don't really see them getting rid of the build number or phone name though.

Comment: Seems Android 9 skips .0 >> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SM-G960F Build/PPR1.180610.011; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/73.0.3683.90 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/218.0.0.46.109;]

Comment: Does not catch Android 10 it catch Android 10.x but It fails on "Android 10"

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the regular expressions to catch major versions with no periods.

Answer (score 2):

May I present an answer that others can easily copy and paste.

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/Android [\d+\.]{3,5}/)[0].replace('Android ','')
```

Answer (score 2):

Motorola's player user agents can have the following:

```
Linux;Android ; Release/4.1.2
```

So, I've had to start using the the following:

```
[a|A]ndroid[^\d]*([\d[_|.]]+\d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex should work, something along the untested lines of

`Android ([0-9]\.[0-9](\.[0-9])?);`

And then use whatever regex function you use to get that part inside the parens.

Comment: This will fail for `Android 1.5`.

Comment: @Marcarse you are right, you will have to adjust for that. I wasn't sure if there was a guaranteed at least a .0 on the end. The edit should fix that issue.

Comment: I'd recommend that you avoid capturing unnecessarily in regex. It's just a good practice and I've been told in some languages it offers performance benefits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it with User-Agent it might be safe but else you shouldn't use it.

```
Android ((\d+|\.)+[^,;]+)
```

It catches everything after Android it works with,

1.6
2.4.4
10.12.5

To test with Live Regex: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/uPw