# Detect Mobile Android Version Number or API Level through User Agent String

Tags: android, jsp, mobile, user-agent, browser-detection

as I am using some CSS styles in a mobile web application which are not working or are not being rendered correctly in Android API versions smaller 8 (Froyo), I am now trying to get the API Level (must be > 7) or Android version number (> 2.1) through the user agent string (I prefer backend detection [JSP] over JavaScript, but this shouldn't matter).

I'm currently checking if user agent (lower case) contains "iphone" OR (contains "android" AND "mobile" AND ??? <- version number)

Another possiblity would propably be to check against the WebKit build number.

Thank you for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding out the Android OS version number might suffice in most cases: you can use either of the following two approaches:

1. Version number: [Get Android OS version from user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293394/get-android-os-version-from-user-agent)
2. Exact device information: https://gist.github.com/2589680

Answer (score 0):

The user agent string from Android does contain the SDK version.

Check this link.
http://www.gtrifonov.com/2011/04/15/google-android-user-agent-strings-2/

I have never seen that to contain a API level, so perhaps you have to manage with SDK version.